# Access- How does one create a caption that disappears upon click?

Tags: ms-access

So I'm making a form and I want it so under the text it says "Optional" and upon typing the word "optional" goes away. Sort of like how the search bar above says "Search..." and upon typing it removes the word "Search...".

Please and Thank you, the learning curve is steep for me so any help will be useful.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'under the text'...   The 'Search...' you mention above is actually text in a textbox. You can load your textbox with the word 'Optional', then add a '.Change' event to remove all but the characters that were entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Format-property of your textbox (1st property on the 1st tab) you can put `@;"Optional"` and you probably want to set the foregroundcolor to some shade of grey.
Then add a keyup-function to reset the text to black when the user enters text:

```
Private Sub myTextbox_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    myTextbox.ForeColor = vbBlack
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your text box (we'll call it Text2) is labeled "Phone Number (Optional):" and the label name is Label1. You could use the Change event as Wayne suggested to change the value of Label1 to just "Phone Number:":

```
Private Sub Text2_Change()
    Label1.Caption = "Phone Number:"
End Sub
```